# Unable to use aws:username to get the current IAM uername in AWS S3 bucket policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am defining a policy on my AWS S3 bucket. I am trying to retrieve the current IAM username dynamically in my bucket policy using `${aws:username}` variable. This is bucket policy.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::1111111111:user/${aws:username}"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/${aws:username}/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

But it is throwing error that policy is invalid when I tried to save it in the console. How can I fix it?

Comment: Is this an IAM policy, or a bucket policy?

Comment: It's a bucket policy.

Comment: I believe those variables are only available in IAM policies, not bucket policies.

Comment: See [Grant Access to User-Specific Folders in an Amazon S3 Bucket](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-grant-access-to-user-specific-folders-in-an-amazon-s3-bucket/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use variables in the [Resource and Condition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html#policy-vars-wheretouse) parts. Remove it from the Principal. For one it doesn't make any sense - it would amount to everyone in the account. You can create a Condition entry to limit access to user/tags/groups etc in which case you can also use variables.

Comment: Thank you. got it. I will change my approach.